# Long c# file breakdown

Tags: c#, code-readability

I have a Window Form App project. At the moment all of my code is in
Form1.cs file which is the default file. Now I have about 1300 lines
of code in this single file. I want to break down this one file code into several files to
increase readability and easy handling. Is there an way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Refactor, refactor, refactor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to do anything drastic you can split your class with the partial keyword and place each piece in its own file.

```
public partial class Form1 { // file1.cs }
public partial class Form1 { // file2.cs }
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: it would be good to get a comment with vote downs as suggested by SO

Comment: I have not downvoted, but in my opinion there are better advice if someone asks how to increase readability and usability on a single-file application. A big mess will not get better if it's cut in halves.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree with you on on that, and concede my answer lacked better advice. That said there may be genuine reasons for not touching the mess eg. legacy code which has a significantly higher cost of refactoring. Dont know for sure but hope the questioner has read the points that Tigran and you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Use Refactor. Select the part of code right click with mouse -> Refactor->Exctract method. Or Ctrl+M combination.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely. You can use [Partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve this.

And this is not only about *readability* of your code, cause it can be even in single file (it depends I mean). But splitting the same code between *different files* will let you be much more flexible in group development when you're using source control.

So multiple team members can work on the same `Form` class, but as they work on different IO artifacts (files), that were devided based on some logic, they will not jump into the conflicts (as much as it possible).

Think about this too.

Comment: I think that suggesting to use partial classes is not the right way to learn OOP.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: absolutely correct. Infact it's not *absoluetly* about learning OOP. Who asks about that ?

Comment: OP wants to increase readability and reusability of his code which is located in a single file. Imho the best way to learn how to split a big thing into many small logical packages is to learn OOP.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: readability is subjective thing, what about usability instead (considering OP mantioned splitting between different files) using partial classes is a way to go. **I personally** don't see in this question anything about OOP difficulties.

Comment: I agree with @Tigran. The question is specific and the answers provided were to the question asked. Anything beyond that is a point of view and should/can not be imposed on any programmer beyond suggesting the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually not a good practice to put all your code into a single class. I recommend you to apply the Separation of Concerns principle and break up that single class into multiple ones, according to their concerns.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

About organizing code: usually people organize code in such a way that 1 file contains 1 class. If that class is too big (and cannot be torn apart), you can still use C#'s partial class feature to organize the same class into multiple files.